# For loops over a list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to apply two 'for' loops (slightly different from each other) on list. First 'for' loop will be from the minimum value to the left side and second from the minimum value to the right side. Following is the list:

```
a = [3,4,6,7,8,4,3,1,6,7,8,9,4]
# to get min index
b = a.index(min(a))
c=a[0:b+1]
d=a[b:len(a)]
for i in reversed(c):
    print i
```

and

```
for i in d:
    print i
```

So for example, first 'for' loop will run from the index value 8 to 1 and second 'for' loop will run from 8 to 13. I am not sure how to run loops in opposite directions starting from the minimum value. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [3,4,6,7,8,4,3,1,6,7,8,9,4]
>>> b = a.index(min(a))
>>> b
7
```

A loop that runs from the index 7 to 0. (not 8 to 1):

```
>>> for i in range(b, -1, -1):
...     print i, a[i]
...
7 1
6 3
5 4
4 8
3 7
2 6
1 4
0 3
```

A loop that run from 8 to 12:

```
>>> for i in range(b+1, len(a)):
...     print i, a[i]
...
8 6
9 7
10 8
11 9
12 4
```

---

```
>>> a[b:None:-1]
[1, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3]
>>> a[b+1:]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 4]
```

**UPDATE**

Followings are more Pythonic methods of getting the index of the minimum value:

```
>>> min(xrange(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)
7
>>> min(enumerate(a), key=lambda L: L[1])[0]
7
>>> import operator
>>> min(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
7
```

Comment: It works. I have also added what I figured in the meanwhile to the OP.

Comment: @Ibe, You can use `c=a[:b+1] d=a[b:]` (omitting `0`, `len(b)`)

Comment: @Ibe, I added another solution that does not require `reversed`.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `min(xrange(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)` and `min(enumerate(a), key=lambda L: L[1])[0]` (or using `itemgetter`) are more Pythonic methods of getting the index of the minimum value...